# Date offset in PHP

Tags: php, date

I am doing my own calendar. For changing to the next and previous months, I use this function:

```
date('m',"-1 months");
date('m',"+1 months");
```

but, when I go to the next month, I can't use this again because **-1** and **+1** are always taken from `now()`.

Assuming that I can't use dynamic numbers to that offset, I mean

```
date('m',"$x months");
```

how can I add or subtract 1 month to a specific date?

For example this date...

```
$date_today = strtotime($_GET['date']);
$next_month = $date_today +/- 1 month ?!?!??!
```

Comment: I doubt you're using literally "`date('m',"-1 months")`".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mix strtotimes up with a reference date so:

```
$next_month=strtotime("+1 month");  // assumes today
$following_month=strtotime("+1 month", $next_month);
```

http://uk.php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php
Takes two parameters and assumes second parameter is time() current timestamp if ommitted

Answer (score 3):

```
$next_month = strtotime('+1 month',$date_today);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `strtotime`...

```
$next_month = strtotime("+1 month");
```

Will give you a unix timestamp which you can pass to `date`...

```
echo date("m", $next_month);
```

Comment: yeah that gives me the next month from now()... but how can i do that from a specific date?

Answer (score 1):

I currently run a calendar for multiple sites with the same issue. I end up storing the current viewable month as a `$_SESSION` variable or pass it as a `$_POST` object when someone clicks on next or prev month.

When you would call it when the next or prev was hit a second time would (or the first time) would be something like

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['viewablemonth']) && $_SESSION['viewablemonth'] = '') {
    $_SESSION['viewablemonth'] = date("m.d.Y");
}
```

End then do your month addition or subtraction:

```
$_SESSION['viewablemonth'] = strtotime("+1 month", $_SESSION['viewablemonth']);
```

Comment: +1 You need to tell your script which month to view. And use it for next prev links

Comment: @Waygood Which by storing it in a passable variable will allow for him to do and will track the current month he is viewing.

Comment: Sorry comment was for OP not you.